# Moving out hibernate template

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I found many useful posts about how to replace HibernateTemplate with SessionFactory directly, however HibernateTemplate has a number of helper methods like `findByCriteria`, is there any open source project which helps in this regard ?

To repharse my question, if I swap out HibernateTemplate is there any open source project which will provide me with the utility methods that HibernateTemplate used to provide ?

Thanks
Sudarshan

Answer (score 2):

There's a section of the Spring manual that discusses [Implementing DAOs based on plain Hibernate 3 API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight). This should contain all the info you need to move away from `HibernateTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks, I am more interested in knowing how to will in the void created by moving away from HibernateTemplate, HibernateTemplate also provides some useful methods which provide an abstraction over the hibernate session, I will be losing this abstraction too.

Comment: @Sudarshan: Yes, that's a choice you have to make. If you want to stick with the raw Hibernate API, you have to live with that API.  If you want to richness of `HibernateTemplate`, then you need to stick with it.

Comment: As of today no Hades equivalent for Hibernate ?, on google code I see something lie Hibernate-Utils, but got no deliverable in it.

Comment: In Spring's hibernate4 support, HibernateTemplate is DROPPED. So when you move to Hibernate 4, you will have to find an alternative. Better to do this now. See <https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096>.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to switch from Hibernate to JPA (2) have a look at [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades), or its successor [Spring-Data-JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Spring open source man...? In Eclipse, if you use Maven and M2Eclipse, just Ctrl-click on HibernateTemplate class, and you can easily adapt the source code to directly interact with the session.